# SELECT Query: I want Date part only from DateTime For Filtering rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datetime

I have table **xxx (,,,,,)**; among these one column has **DateTime** datatype (say **Login_date**)

Login_date has values like: `"  27-Nov-13 3:12:07 PM "`

My Problem is that

i want to select the rows of table xxx where Login_date is `" 27-Nov-13 "`
i am getting error when executing a query like this

```
DateTime dt=new DateTime();
dt=DateTime.Now;
Command Query is:      " SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE (Login_Date=@date)  "
cmd.Parameters.add("@date",dt);

This is not selecting any rows from table xxx.
```

This is not working because of **difference in Time**.

& here i am using ***MYSQL*** data base
Please bring me out of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

pls try this,

```
 var dt=DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```

Comment: See i want it to change in SQL query, Not in Program..!

Comment: **NO**  If he has a date/time type in the database, changing the application variable to a string won't help.  In fact, depending on a number of settings, this may get completely wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yy")
```

So when adding your parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.add("@date",dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yy"));
```

Comment: its fine, but how do u write in command query..?
It will Not Work.. I already Tested.

Comment: it is not selecting any rows because there is time difference though dates are same.

Comment: Please see my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20240165/1185053)

Comment: **NO**. If he has a date/time type in the database, changing the application variable to a string won't help. In fact, depending on a number of settings, this may get completely wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Try where `convert(datetime, cast(login_date as varchar(12)),103)='27-Nov-13'`

I always find the following page on DateTime an excellent resource: [`sql server datetime workbench`](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/robyn-pages-sql-server-datetime-workbench/)

Comment: Using SQL server this may Execute....
But i need it in MY-SQl server..

Comment: **NO.** Converting to a string is not a good option. Not only will this ignore any indices on the column, but it has a chance to go wrong in other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE (DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Login_Date)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date)))");
cmd.Parameters.add("@date", dt);
```

this way we are comparing only date without time.

Comment: er, doing this kind of date math will cause the optimizer to not use any index on that column, meaning the query will take longer than it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Today; // Note Today, not Now
Command Query is:      
"SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE Login_Date>=@date AND Login_Date < DATEADD(d,1,@date)"
cmd.Parameters.add("@date",dt);
```

Using a date range in your query like this can be more efficient than casting to DATE because it enables you to take advantage of any index there may be on the DATETIME column.

Comment: This may work in SQL server, But i wanted in MYSQL server..
Please Help;

Answer (score 0):

try below query,

`SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE (convert(date,Login_Date,101))=convert(date,@date,101)`

Comment: Converting the column this way will cause the optimizer to ignore any indices, meaning the query will take longer than it needs to.

Comment: working fine(CAST & CONVERT) in select query but not in Update query..

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
CREATE TABLE #tabledates ( dt DATETIME )

INSERT  INTO #tabledates
        ( dt )
VALUES  ( '2013-11-27 10:30:07' )

INSERT  INTO #tabledates
        ( dt )
VALUES  ( '2013-11-27 10:30:07' )

INSERT  INTO #tabledates
        ( dt )
VALUES  ( '2013-11-28 10:30:07' )

INSERT  INTO #tabledates
        ( dt )
VALUES  ( '2013-11-28 10:30:07' ) 

SELECT  *
FROM    #tabledates
WHERE   DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dt)) = '2013-11-28'
```

So, in your case, you would have...

```
DateTime dt=new DateTime();
dt=DateTime.Now;
Command Query is:"SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE 
                    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Login_Date))=@date"
cmd.Parameters.add("@date",dt);
```

Comment: Doing this (converting/doing date math) will completely invalidate the use of any indices on that column for a search, meaning this is going to take longer than it should.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this as your command query:

```
SELECT [t0].[Column], [t0].[Date]
FROM [Table] AS [t0]
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[Date]) = @p0
```

And use:

```
var dt = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: This will work in SQL-Server...
But i need in **MY-SQL** server...
Please Try some..

Comment: He shouldn't need to convert the column to get the answer.  Among other things, this will completely invalidate the use of any index during query execution, meaning it's going to take longer than it should.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
SELECT * FROM xxx  WHERE (CONVERT(varchar(10), Login_Date,110)='27-Nov-13')
```

Comment: Using sql server this may execute..
But i am using MYSQL server..

Comment: **NO.**  Converting to a string is _not_ a good option.  Not only will this ignore any indices on the column, but it has a chance to go wrong in other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe's answer is correct, but unfortunately is written for SQL Server.
Here's a version for MySQL:

```
SELECT Login_Date
FROM tabledates
WHERE Login_Date >= DATE(@date)
      AND Login_Date < DATE_ADD(DATE(@date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

(working [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8609d/1), only with an explicit timestamp instead of the replacement variable)
Will use an index, if available.

Answer (score 0):

Having an index on a date/time variable is not the best practice. I'd suggest that you create another field in the table, which will have only the date value, and then it would be easy to execute your own script and that will retrieve to you exactly what is needed.
In case this solution is not doable; I'd suggest that you use:

```
SELECT *
FROM xxx
WHERE Login_Date BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2
```

Where Date1 will be the date of when you want the Login attempts to show (November 27, 2013)
and Date2 will be the next day (November 28, 2013)

***N.B.:** The most important thing to keep in your mind, in the second example, that you make sure that the times are 00:00.000, so no attempts would be included from the next day*